# FRQ High Scores Part B: I'm getting a "missing a return statement" when the returns are in the for loop? Shouldn't the returns be reached?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm a high schooler in apcs and I'm trying to practice these for the test. The code should return whether a new object was created. Also, the moveUp method doesn't allow me to call it using the scoreboard list (e.g. "scoreboard.move(int x)". Please explain why I'm wrong, but don't solve it.

```
public boolean newScore(String name, int score)
  {
    /* Implement your answer to part (b) here */
    for (int ind = 0; ind < scoreboard.size(); ind++) {
      Player player = scoreboard.get(ind);
      if (player.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
        player.updateScore(score);
        moveUp(scoreboard.indexOf(player));
        return true;
      } else {
        Player p = new Player(name, score);
        scoreboard.add(p);
        p.updateScore(score);
        moveUp(scoreboard.indexOf(p)); 
       return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: What if your `scoreboard` was empty?

Comment: Two things. If the size of your scoreboard is zero, then the loop will not execute, and therefore neither return statement will be reached. So you do need a final return statement. Secondly, the loop will only execute once. If the first player is found, it returns, otherwise it creates a new player and returns.

Comment: Thanks! Also, why doesn't the moveUp() method need an object (it's nonstatic)?

Comment: The method ```newScore()``` is not static, therefore it can only be reached once its class is instantiated. I assume that ```moveUp()``` is part of the same class, and so can be reached from within ```newScore()```.

Comment: Isn't moveUp() a method for the scoreboard list?

Comment: I don't know. You didn't provide the class code. I am *assuming* that both methods are in the same class, therefore when you instantiate the class, both methods are available to be used as part of the class.